What is the meaning of 10000 in the triple aarch64-linux-android10000?
What is the meaning of 10000 in the triple aarch64-linux-android10000?
Is it perhaps Android version (10.000)?
There is a similar question posted on Android Help Community (support.google.com/android). The answer is to "find the information you need on the Android Developers' forum". I found this question on Android Developers' forum (forums.androidcentral.com). The answer is to "ask this question at XDA Forum". I couldn't find this question on XDA Forum (xdaforums.com), because couldn't find the "search" / "find" option / feature there.

UPD. Links to the source where aarch64-linux-android10000 is used: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/+/refs/tags/ndk-r23-beta2/BUILD.bazel#118.

Please provide a link to the source where you have found aarch64-linux-android10000 (not the questions, the real source where it is used).

@Robert See UPD.

The interesting part is that it also exists in an x86 version: --target=x86_64-linux-android10000, therefore it doesn't seem to be related to the CPU architecture (I first thought may be the is the Google way to differ between the two 64bit arm architectures arm-v8a and arm-v9).

@Robert There is aarch64-none-linux-android21 as well. CMake produces -- Android: Targeting API '21' .... Hence, it seems that 21 is API version. Hence, 10000 may be API version 10.000.
